Why am I receiving an conversion error on my date and time values(s)?
I'm connecting to to sql server view using jdbc connector from databricks notebook
df = spark.read
          .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")
          .option("url", url)
          .option("dbtable", table_name)
          .option("user", key)
          .option("password", password)
          .load()

view has couple of columns with 'Date' datatype and 'Varchar'
all date column values are in correct format 'yyyy-MM-dd' and there are no null or corrupted values.
This error occurs when I try to do some aggregations to the DF
Error Message:

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

There's no errors when i convert the dataframe to RDD and convert back to DF. The thing is it's takes more time and resources.
Is there anyway of loading the view as a RDD in the first place or any other work around to optimize the code.
following is the schema of the view

Here's code snippet where I get the error
plan_df.groupBy("FrozenDateKey")
        .agg(
            F.min(planned_date).alias("min_planned_date"),
            F.max(planned_date).alias("max_planned_date"),
        )


"view has couple of columns with 'Date' datatype and 'Varchar'" are you saying some of your date (and time) columns are a varchar? If so, that's the problem.

You probably have to include the grouping code and view definition

Provide a predifined schema where you read all date columns into string format. Then after reading you can convert the columns to dateformat.

I've edited the question
@ThomA yes it has string and float as well.

@siggemannen code is included now

MAX for "ID" columns? Using a column that is likely to be over 4,000 characters is a terrible ID candidate. I doubt float is the correct data for a column that's meant to be a quantity either; I assume some kind of integer data type would be far better.

@user238607 It worked. Any idea why this is happening?

@Madushan : maybe the first comment by @ Thom A could provide you with hints on how to investigate this.
